# setType storing only uppercase

Tags: java

I'm working a project for my intro to Java class and one of the UML methods in the Public BookOrder class is the following:

```
+setType(type:char):void
// accepts (R,r,O,o,P,p,F,f,U,u,N), but stores
// UPPERcase letters. For any other type entered, the value N is stored
```

From this, I have two questions:

1. Will the following code work?

   ```
   public class BookOrder
   {
   private String author;      
   private String title;
   private int quantity;
   private double costPerBook;
   private String orderDate;
   private double weight;
   private char type;      //R,O,F,U,N


   public void setType(char type)
   {
       if (type=r || type=R || type=o || type= O || type= f || type= F || type= u || type= U || type= n || type= N)
           this.type= type;
       else
           this.type= N;
   }
   ```
2. How do I get it to store only uppercase letters? I read that Character.isUpperCase would work but I was told in class you could only do String.toUpperCase, not char.

Comment: _"Will the following code work?"_ You can try and see

Comment: Define `work`.  We don't see where `this.type` is defined.

Comment: Actually, atm I can't. I have a lot of methods without returns left to write, so if I try to compile, it just throws those as errors, nothing else.

Comment: You actually can try it and see: your code should be orthogonal. If you write a function like you have above in a new, empty project, you should be able to run code against it to see if it works as you expect. Look into `JUnit`.

Answer (score 0):

replace each of your conditions like this

```
type=='r'
```

Since java uses == to check equality and ' ' is needed to represent chars

Answer (score 0):

```
if (type=='r' || type=='R' /*etc etc*/)
{
    if(type < 97) //Upper case
        this.type = type;
    else //Lower case
        this.type = (type - 32);
}
```

Or...

```
else
    this.type = ((String.valueOf(type)).toUpperCase()).charAt(0);
```

This converts `type` to a `String`, capitalizes it, then converts it back to a `char` to assign to `this.type`.

Comment: This makes perfect sense and should work great, the only problem is that it throws an error saying "Loss of precision" required: char; found: int.

Comment: It's an error. And yes, I have it positioned within the else part just as you have it above.

Comment: You can try replacing `32` with `' '` (the space character, which has an ASCII value of 32).  Otherwise, I'll edit in a nasty super nested method for capitalizing...

Comment: I tried inserting ' ' and it still gave me an error with the minus sign. The edit worked, although that is something I shoudln't know at this point in my class, I'll just comment it and tell him I had to do some research to get that. Lol. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be careful when comparing things. When comparing strings the == operator checks for reference values. It is a much safer bet to use the Strings.equals function(if you are allowed, or make your own).

```
import java.util.*;

public class Main{

    public static String setType(String type)
    {
        if (type.equals("r") || type.equals("R") || type.equals("o") || type.equals("O") || type.equals("f") || type.equals("F") || type.equals("u") || type.equals("U") || type.equals("n") || type.equals("N"))
            type=type;
        else
            type="N";

        return type;
    }


   public static void main(String [] args){
    System.out.println("Try different stuff");
    System.out.printf("%s\n",setType(args[0]));
   } 
}
```

In this example I take in arguments from the command line and then compare them to specified values. It might be helpful to read the java function documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html